# Representing classes as enums and having knowledge of other class members between them

Tags: c++, enums, polymorphism

## Background

I have a enum class that represents different cities.

`enum class City {London, Manchester, Birmingham, Portsmouth}`;

I also have a lot of maps to help assign information to each city. These maps are in the double digits and are dotted around the project, quickly becoming difficult to maintain.

```
std::map<City, std::string> cityName = {{City.London, "London"}, {City.Manchester, "Manchester"}, ...};
std::map<City, bool> hasLargePopulation = {{City.London, true}, {City.Manchester, false}, ...};
...
```

So I decided the best thing to do would be to encapsulate all this information for each city by creating a polymorphic class system (cities.h), and then creating pointers for each one (citydeclarations.h) and using that instead of a enum type (cityenumlogic.h). e.g.

cities.h

```
class City {
public:
    std::string _name;
    bool _hasLargePopulation;
    City(std::string name, bool hasLargePopulation) : _name(name), _hasLargePopulation(hasLargePopulation) {}
};
...
```

citydeclarations.h

```
inline City* london = new City("london", true);
inline City* birmingham = new City("birmingham", false);
...
```

cityenumlogic.h

```
bool isSameCity(City* city1, City* city2) {
     return city1 == city2;
}
```

## Problem

There is one more function that I'd like to encapsulate into the base `City` class, that is not possible now that the different city types are not known. This is a function that returns true/false if it is possible to travel from one city to another using the breadth first search algorithm which uses a map of cities to a vector of cities called `paths` to determine if it is possible to travel from one city to another.

```
std::map<City, std::vector<City>> paths = {{City.London, {City.Birmingham, City.Portsmouth}},...};
bool canTravel(City city1, City city2); //uses BFS with 'paths' to determine if possible route exists
```

The `canTravel` function could be stored within the base `City` class, but it is not possible to declare the paths a certain city can take in the constructor because it might be the case that a city is not declared yet.

Furthermore where would a complete list of all the paths of each city (to be used by the `City::canTravel`) be stored, since the paths of other cities are not known? Any advice/tips with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Goal:

```
if(london->canTravel(birmingham))
   ...
```

Comment: Each`city` can have a member `m_path`  that is an empty `std::vector<City>` .  You can then create a method called `setPath( std::vector<City>)`. Once all cities are instatiated you can call this function for each city and set each path.

Comment: More related: It looks like you want your `City` class to be some sort of graph. Or possibly no class at all and a big look-up table.

Comment: "creating a polymorphic class system" There is nothing polymorphic in this class so far. `london->canTravel` This is probably not a good idea. Why should a city be ever aware of other cities, all different kinds of transportation, all roads, and whatever else it takes to travel? It seems traveling between cities is a function of a road network a.k.a. "graph", which deserves its own class, and each city can be on any number of such networks.